# How can I create custom exception in ColdFusion

Tags: exception, coldfusion

Here is an example of my code:

```
<cftry>

    <cfquery name="myquery" datasource="logindetails">
        INSERT INTO userdetails
        (FirstName,LastName,Email,Phonenumber,Country,Gender)
        VALUES
        ('#Form.firstname#','#Form.lastname#','#Form.emailID#',
        '#Form.PhoneNumber#','#Form.country#','#Form.gender#')
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>
        <b>Your Form has been registered</b>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfcatch type="database">
        <cfoutput>Email already exists. Try with a different email address</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfoutput>Sorry! some error occured.</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

I have two different database exceptions and I want to display different messages for these two exceptions form the database so I am asking how to create custom exceptions in ColdFusion?

Comment: Assuming you have that code block wrapped in `cftry` tags, how is what you have not working for you?

Comment: Not related to your question, but be sure to always use `cfqueryparam` on all client supplied values. Both to improve performance and guard against sql injection.

Comment: I would check for email dups first. That way we could avoid a common scenario. I like avoiding try / catch if possible.

Comment: Agreed. Prevention is usually a better course of action for errors you can predict and handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if it's possible to have custom messages for two different exceptions thrown by the cfquery (rather than custom exceptions which can be done with [cfthrow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e25.html))

if so any error coming from the cfquery will probably be of type database so you'll have to inspect the message in the cfcatch and alter the message depending on the content of the error message for example

```
<cftry>

    <cfquery name="myquery" datasource="logindetails">
        INSERT INTO userdetails
        (FirstName,LastName,Email,Phonenumber,Country,Gender)
        VALUES
        ('#Form.firstname#','#Form.lastname#','#Form.emailID#',
        '#Form.PhoneNumber#','#Form.country#','#Form.gender#')
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>
        <b>Your Form has been registered</b>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfcatch type="database">
        <cfoutput>#findNoCase("error message 1", cfcatch.message) ? "Email already exists. Try with a different email address" : "Some other error message"#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfoutput>Sorry! some error occured.</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

Possibly you will need to inspect multiple properties depending on the error returned from the db so [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/reserved-words-and-variables/coldfusion-tag-specific-variables/cfcatch-variables.html) is a list of cfcatch properties

Answer (score 1):

Custom exceptions in ColdFusion are created with the `<cfthrow>` tag.  Here is one of the many documents on the topic:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cfthrow.html